# How to select certain keys and corresponding values using docinfo.items() in pikepdf (python) during extraction of metadata

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, metadata

I am trying this code to extract metadata for a pdf
There is author and then title, I want values for only author and title from the metadata
'''
`import pikepdf`
`pdf = pikepdf.open(path)`
`docinfo = pdf.docinfo`
`for key, value in docinfo.items():`
`if str(key).startswith("A") == True or str(key).startswith("Ti") == True:`
`print(key, ":", value)`
'''
The code runs but gives no output

Answer (score 1):

```
def pdfs():
    pdf = pikepdf.open("/full/path/to/pdf.pdf")
    docinfo = pdf.docinfo
    for key, value in docinfo.items():
        print(key, ":", value)
```

Output:

/Producer : Name

/Title : Another name

Here's the documentation as well:  https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pikepdf/latest/pikepdf.pdf